# how to loop multidimensional object with *ngFor in angular 4

Tags: angular

[image]

I try to loop that object with `*ngFor` in my html.

```
<tr *ngFor="let artikel of artikels">

</tr>
```

but that give me the error

[image]

Can somebody help me how to loop this object?

I'm new to angular too.. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post example code of your object?

Comment: You can't use object with `*ngFor` to loop with. `*ngFor` only allows array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over objects with *ngFor, as the error say's you need to use an array like data structure.

The best solution is to use pipe with your *ngFor that transform your object into an array.

Try to add this pipe to your util's module:

```
@Pipe({name: 'objectToArray'})
export class objectToArray implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
```

Import the pipe into your module and use it with your *ngFor

```
<tr *ngFor="let articleKey of article|objectToArray">

</tr>
```

Now you can use 'articleKey' and use it to loop over the nested array:

```
<tr *ngFor="let articleKey of article|objectToArray">
   <td *ngFor="let article of article[articleKey]">
       <!--your template-->
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It should be **impure** pipe, like a **json** **slice** pipes. If object properties changes, for example added new property or removed. Then it should be updated in html too. Look at [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-pure-and-impure-pipes-and-why-that-matters-999818aa068)