# How to display following object in angular5 html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, angular5

[image: Display object angular5]

In the above screenshot console I have an object with 2 values **users** and **tickers**. Again each one is array of values.

Now how to display these values in angular5 html template as specified in above screenshot?

I am trying to use ngFor but it is showing errors.

Comment: share your code (via plunk or stackblitz) and what you have done.. go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: You have not shared the object not even the code.

Comment: Would you please post what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your data:

```
    public data = {
      tickers:[
         {id:"1",name:"Ticker Name 1", company:"Company 1"},
         {id:"2",name:"Ticker Name 2", company:"comapny 2"}
      ],
    users:[
         {id:"1",first_name:"User1 ", last_name:"u1last", email:"user1@test.com"},
         {id:"2",first_name:"User2", last_name:"u2last", email:"user2@test.com"},
         {id:"3",first_name:"User3", last_name:"u3last", email:"user3@test.com"},
         {id:"4",first_name:"User4", last_name:"u4last", email:"user4@test.com"}
      ]
  };

  public dataKeys; // This will hold the main Object Keys.
```

The constructor will look something like this:

```
 constructor() {
     this.dataKeys = Object.keys(this.data);
}
```

Here is the simple HTML that you need to write:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of dataKeys">
  <h3>{{ key }}</h3>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let d of data[key]">{{d.name || d.first_name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the complete working plunker for your case:

[Click here to view the Working Solution](https://embed.plnkr.co/QVATF7NiNKmdKKiG0DNm/)

Comment: Hi Fahad, data is correct format. But here users,tickers,sectors....etc this is also dynamic. it has many values and comes few values dynamically.

Comment: @DRK i have modified the answer. Now it will check everything dynamically. It will be better to use the same key for Name in all objects.

Comment: Thanks. For constructor statement getting 'Cannot convert undefined or null to object' error. Actually you are initialized data starting. But for me I declared variable top then in constructor put your statement and then I am getting data in one method

Comment: ok got it. Then you should write the this.dataKeys = Object.keys(this.data); after the function call in which you are getting data. and remove it from constructor.

Comment: Solved. I put your constructor statement after getting data in my method. Now working fine. Thanks. Up vote to you

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Can you accept the answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use json pipe for debug purpose like this:

   ```
   {{object |json}}
   ```
2. If you want exactly as in picture, look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49276529/5677886). With this case, you don't need to manually write first level property names of object in template for using ***ngFor**

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that,

```
<ul>
  <P>users</p>
  <li *ngFor="let item of object.users; let i = index">
    {{i}}. {{item.frist_name}}
  </li>
<P>Tickets</p>
  <li *ngFor="let item of object.tickers; let i = index">
    {{i}}. {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here users,tickers are dynamic. we can't say these only come.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) it should be this:

```
Users:
<ol>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.first_name}}</li>
</ol>
Tickets:
<ol>
    <li *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">{{ticket.name}}</li>
</ol>
```